# Rails ActiveRecord: Does accepts_nested_attributes_for mark a parent record as dirty even if parent attributes are unchanged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm syncing data with an iPhone app, so it's important to know which records have been "actually" updated and which ones have not.  I've got an Event model with a RelatedLink association:

In event.rb:

```
has_many :related_links
accepts_nested_attributes_for :related_links, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:url].blank? && a[:id].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

On my event form, when I change nothing, including the RelatedLink field, I'm good ... nothing is updated on my Event model. But if I enter a url in my RelatedLink field, "updated_at" on my Event object is updated.

```
UPDATE "events" SET "updated_at" = '2011-05-30 15:27:03.228435' WHERE "events"."id" = 1791
```

Should it work that way?  Can I stop it from being marked dirty and being updated?

Answer (score 3):

If the parent model's attributes don't change then the record IS NOT considered dirty and the `updated_at` shouldn't change. Take this for example (Rails 3.2.3)

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :comments_attributes

  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :author
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Rails console test (I only kept relevant output when I pasted this in)

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > p = Post.create :title => "Nested attributes", :body => "Nested attributes are awesome", :comments_attributes => [{ :body => "I agree", :author => "Bart" }]
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "Nested attributes", body: "Nested attributes are awesome", created_at: "2012-06-13 01:49:34", updated_at: "2012-06-13 01:49:34"> 

1.9.3p194 :002 > last_post = Post.last
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "Nested attributes", body: "Nested attributes are awesome", created_at: "2012-06-13 01:49:34", updated_at: "2012-06-13 01:49:34"> 

1.9.3p194 :003 > last_post.comments_attributes = [{:id => 1, :author => "Bort"}]
=> [{:id=>1, :author=>"Bort"}] 

1.9.3p194 :004 > last_post.changed?
=> false 

1.9.3p194 :005 > last_post.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.7ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "author" = 'Bort', "updated_at" = '2012-06-13 01:51:05.032862' WHERE "comments"."id" = 1
(250.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true 

1.9.3p194 :006 > last_post.updated_at
=> Wed, 13 Jun 2012 01:49:34 UTC +00:00
```

So there must be something else in your case that is causing an update to be fired on the `Event`. Check to see if there are any [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) that might be doing this and also check to see whether your `belongs_to` method isn't defined with the `:touch` option. For example

```
belongs_to :event, :touch => true
```